# javascript timer MIA (no longer calls function)

Tags: javascript, timer

I have a timer that goes awol every once in a while...

```
timer_clock=setInterval('update_time()',1000)
```

Sometimes `update_time()` stops being called (no longer gets called again ever).

I placed some code to track when this happens (have not found exactly when or where, just that it is no longer calling `update_time()`. In this code I test `timer_clock` and it returns true.

There is no `clearInterval` being applied anywhere.

What can cause a timer to stop calling its function?

Edit: This is on a page with many `iframes` containing complex pages.
It usually happens after a specific `XMLHttpRequest`, but it does not happen every time that request is made (less than 1% of the time), and it has happened at other times. There is nothing in the code following the request that should interfere with the timer.

Comment: You don't get any errors in your console? Does the tab freeze?

Comment: No error messages, app continues to run as normal, other than the clock.

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: App only runs on firefox

Comment: Can you reproduce it in JSFiddle?

Comment: Only happens every several days, that is why I have not been able to locate where exactly it begins.

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem.  Have you found a solution to it yet?

Comment: The issue has gone away, never found what caused or solved it, sorry.